# Two "Different" Buttons from Single UIButton?

Tags: swift, uibutton

I've got a basic array of buttons that I'd like to change functionality and look based on whether the user has pressed a "shift"-type separate button.

```
@IBOutlet var shiftBtn: UIButton!
@IBAction func shiftBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
      changeLookOfsomeBtns() /* ?? */
    }

@IBOutlet var someBtns: [UIButton]!
@IBAction func someBtns(_ sender: UIButton) {
      if shiftBtn.selected == true {
          doSomething()
      } else if shiftBtn.selected == false {
          doSomethingElse()
```

}

Is this the right approach?  I'm stuck on what technique to apply to change both the function options and image for someBtns.

Thanks!

Comment: By default UIButtons don't have a state property. Have you considered using an UISegmentControl to shift this property? If you really need to use a shift UIButton, an easy way would be to save a "selected" Bool var and use its property

Comment: @alxlives UISegmentControl would be great; however I need to run the "shift" from a singe UIButton.  Could you elaborate on the "selected" Bool process you mentioned? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
if shiftBtn.selected == true {
    doSomething()
} else if shiftBtn.selected == false {
    doSomethingElse()
}
```

You seem to be checking a (non-existent) property on a button to decide what to do. In general, you shouldn't make decisions based on a button's property. Instead, you should have a separate property (let's call it `shifted`) that indicates whether the shift button is activated or not.

```
var shifted = false {
    didSet {
        if shifted {
            changeSomeButtonsToShiftedAppearance()
        } else {
            changeSomeButtonsToNormalAppearance()
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func someBtns(_ sender: UIButton) {
      if shifted {
          doSomething()
      } else {
          doSomethingElse()
}
```

And you set this property when shift is pressed:

```
@IBAction func shiftBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
    shifted = !shifted
}
```